# Create firebase auth token which never expires

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are generating custom firebase auth tokens. Unfortunately, the maximum lifetime of such a token is one hour: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens?hl=en#letting_the_admin_sdk_discover_a_service_account

We are generating these tokens to act as the Bearer auth for a web service api. In this context, it is not appropriate to expire a token. Doing so runs a very high risk of clients losing revenue. Even if you were to expire them, one hour is comically short for an expiration. Consequently, we need jwt tokens which do not expire. Does anyone know how to do this with the firebase auth system?

Comment: The custom token is used when you have your own auth system but want to use Firebase Auth for your web app. The ID Token you get after user is logged in on client does expire every hour but the Firebase SDK refreshes it without you needing to do anything. Can you provide more details on what your client side looks like i.e. are you logging in user using Firebase auth?

Comment: The client does not use the firebase sdk to login. We have created a REST api, so the client authorizes their requests by including the auth token in the Authorization header of their requests. They get these tokens from a webapp the same way you do for most web services (pubnub, github, etc)

Comment: then you have two options: either 1. you look for away to have the client to sign in with custom token and then use firebase callable functions to make requests (that way you can identify the signed in user from context.auth) and you won't need to set Authorization header or 2. use your own JWT tokens without firebase. You know, Firebase custom tokens are for the client and not for the admin SDK.

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude thank you. It seems firebase defeats the purpose of using itself. We went with this platform to abstract away common development tasks, but this and other experiences have given me the impression we should have just used a combination of aws services.

Comment: yes firebase is a backend service but it can't do everything you know. It favours serverless architecture but not creating well customised APIs as you do. please I will post the above comment as an answer, please mark it as answer to help my points, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments:

As @Dharmaraj said, The custom auth token from the admin SDK is for signing in the user immediately and expires in an hour. You can't increase the expiry time. Firebase takes care of refreshing the sign-in state with tokens from their servers.

But given that you need this for web service API and you don't need the user to sign in you have two options:

1. Look for a way to have the client sign in with the custom token and then use firebase callable functions to make requests (you can identify the signed-in user from context.auth). Also, you won't need to set the Authorization header
2. Use your own JWT tokens without firebase. Firebase custom tokens are for the client and not for the admin SDK.

Firebase is a backend service and can't do everything. It favors serverless architecture and not the creation of well-customized APIs as you want.